# Matching string and then characters until a specified string appears again

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
<tr><td>2.</td></tr><tr><td colspan="25"><img src="/adad4.gif" alt="" align="middle"></td></tr><tr><td>3.</td></tr><tr><td colspan="25"><img src="/h5s6c.gif" alt="" align="middle"></td></tr><tr><td>4.</td></tr><tr><td>5.</td><td>2</td></tr>
```

I want to remove alle occurrences of

```
<tr><td colspan="25"><img src="/somegifname.gif" alt="" align="middle"></td></tr>
```

part. But how?

In short I want to remove everything from

```
<tr><td colspan="25">
```

to the first following occurrence of

```
</tr>
```

and include both of those string in the removal as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# using regular expression:

```
var regex =
   new Regex(
      "<tr><td colspan=\"25\">.*?</tr>"
   );

var result =
   regex.Replace(
      "<tr><td>2.</td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"25\"><img src=\"/adad4.gif\" alt=\"\" align=\"middle\"></td></tr><tr><td>3.</td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"25\"><img src=\"/h5s6c.gif\" alt=\"\" align=\"middle\"></td></tr><tr><td>4.</td></tr><tr><td>5.</td><td>2</td></tr>",
      ""
   );
```

Note the question mark in `<tr><td colspan=\"25\">.*?</tr>` this removes the shortest match.